# Changing the style of html tag by clicking on another

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, the parentAppliance is part of main left nav table and on hovering over "Appliance" I see a subtable containing "health". Now I want the subtable to disappear when I click on health, any thoughts?

CSS:

```
.childAppliance
    {
        display:none;
    }
.parentAppliance:hover .childAppliance
    {
        display: block;
        top: 50px;
        left: 130px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<li id="Appliance" itemid="Appliance" class="parentAppliance" role="presentation">
    <a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Appliance" id="ui-id-83" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" title="" data-original-title="">
        <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span><ins class="ui-navigation-static-menu-icon ui-navigation-static-menu-icon-backup"></ins>
        <span class="ui-navigation-static-menu-text" style="display: inline;">Appliance</span>
    </a>
    <ul id="ApplianceSubTable" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all childAppliance" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-83">
        <li itemid="Health" class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
            <a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Health" id="ui-id-33" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-focus applianceFocus" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" title="">
                <span class="ui-navigation-static-menu-text">Health</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: CSS does not have click events. Look at jQuery or plain JavaScript.

Comment: @isherwood CSS actually can have click events through radio tabs. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/UbF9a/ (not saying this is the most practice way but it is possible :})

Comment: True, but not on general elements like would be needed for this question.

Comment: I know that I could use javascript code below:
function hide(obj) {
    var element = document.getElementById(obj);
    element.style.display = 'none';
}

And make the following HTML code modification:

<a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Health" id="ui-id-33" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-focus applianceFocus" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" title="" onclick="hide('ApplianceSubTable');>

This gets what I want, but when I hover over "Appliance" again, the table does not show up.

Comment: -1 for duplicating questions

Comment: Actually :active is essentially a click event... See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `onmouseover` event to the parent appliance and an additional JavaScript method to reset the child display state.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
     .childAppliance
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .parentAppliance:hover .childAppliance
    {
        display: block;
        top: 50px;
        left: 130px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(obj) { 
            var element = document.getElementById(obj);

            if(element.style.display == 'none')
                element.style.display = 'block';
            else
                element.style.display = 'none';
        }

        function show(obj) {
            var element = document.getElementById(obj);
            element.style.display = '';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<li id="Appliance" itemid="Appliance" class="parentAppliance" role="presentation">
    <a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Health" id="A1" 
        class="ui-corner-all ui-state-focus applianceFocus" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" title="" 
        onclick="toggle('ApplianceSubTable');" onmouseover="show('ApplianceSubTable');">

    <!--<a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Appliance" id="ui-id-83" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" title="" data-original-title="">-->
        <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span><ins class="ui-navigation-static-menu-icon ui-navigation-static-menu-icon-backup"></ins>
        <span class="ui-navigation-static-menu-text" style="display: inline;">Appliance</span>
    </a>
    <ul id="ApplianceSubTable" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all childAppliance" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-83">
        <li itemid="Health" class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
            <a href="#/appliance_status.home" hiddentitle="Health" id="ui-id-33" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-focus applianceFocus" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" title="">
                <span class="ui-navigation-static-menu-text">Health</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks jim31415. I was half way through implementing your suggestion and it works :) Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Use :active to set display back to none.

```
.ui-navigation-static-menu-text:active{
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vXU2t/

Comment: But the element also disappears on mouseout.